# Automatically Expand RowDetails of Newly Added Rows of a RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, radgridview

**What I want to solve:**
When new items are added to a RadGridView new rows are created accordingly. I want those new rows to automatically have expanded RowDetails.

**What I tried so far:**
I tried to access the RadGridView from code-behind and register an event handler that listens for new items. It will mark the new item as selected and thereby expand the RowDetails (RowDetailsVisibilityMode is VisibleWhenSelected).

**The problems I'm facing:**
The RadGridView is sitting inside the data template of another control's resources. If I set an explicit `x:Key` for the data template, I can access the data template through code; however, if I only set a `DataType` for the data template, each dictionary entry in the resources has a null value.

The problem is that if I do set an explicit `x:Key` for the data template, I can no longer have my control dynamically decide which data template to use based on the data type (no data template is chosen, and I just see a big blank space). How do I get at the control inside the data template?

Here's my code:

XAML:

```
<telerik:RadTabControl x:Name="radTabControl">
    <telerik:RadTabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TabControlTemplate">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <!-- Wrapper1 (inherits from Wrapper) -->
                    <DataTemplate DataType="local:Wrapper1Collection">
                        <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        ....
                        </telerik:RadGridView>
                    </DataTemplate>

                    <!-- Wrapper2 (inherits from Wrapper) -->
                    <DataTemplate DataType="local:Wrapper2Collection">
                        <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        ....
                        </telerik:RadGridView>
                    </DataTemplate>

                    <!-- Fallback to displaying nothing for unknown wrapper types -->
                    <DataTemplate DataType="local:WrapperCollection" />
                </ContentControl.Resources>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadTabControl.Resources>

    <telerik:RadTabItem Content="{Binding Path=Wrappers}"
                        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TabControlTemplate}" />
    <telerik:RadTabItem Content="{Binding Path=Wrappers}"
                        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TabControlTemplate}" />
</telerik:RadTabControl>
```

C# Code-Behind:

```
public ContentUpdateView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataTemplate tabControlTemplate =
        (DataTemplate)(radTabControl.Resources["TabControlTemplate"]);
    FrameworkElement radGridViewContentControl =
        (FrameworkElement)(tabControlTemplate.LoadContent());

    foreach (DictionaryEntry resourceEntry in radGridViewContentControl.Resources)
    {
        if (resourceEntry.Value != null)
        {
            DataTemplate radGridViewDataTemplate = (DataTemplate)(resourceEntry.Value);
            RadGridView radGridView = (RadGridView)(radGridViewDataTemplate.LoadContent());

            radGridView.Items.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                {
                    foreach (Wrapper wrapper in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        radGridView.SelectedItems.Add(wrapper);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `Wrapper` class is an abstract class which `Wrapper1` and `Wrapper2` inherit from, and that the `Wrappers` path on my viewmodel is a `WrapperCollection`, which is an abstract class that inherits from `ObservableCollection<Wrapper>`, and which `Wrapper1Collection` and `Wrapper2Collection` inherit from.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that a newly added row is automatically expanded.

Comment: Attach a custom `Behavior` to your `RadGridView` that listens for newly added rows and expands them. Your current approach can't possibly work.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific please? A code example would be great. Which event would I need to attach to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, based on your comments I won't answer "*How to access [...] resources [...]?*" but try to give an answer for "*How to automatically expand RowDetails of newly added rows of a RadGridView?*".

I recommed a custom `Behavior` for your `RadGridView` that listens for newly added rows and performs the RowDetail expansion.

```
<RadGridView>
    <Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ExpandDetailsOfNewRowsBehavior/>
    </Interaction.Behaviors>
</RadGridView>
```

and code:

```
public class ExpandDetailsOfNewRowsBehavior : Behavior<RadGridView>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        INotifyCollectionChanged items = AssociatedObject.Items;
        items.CollectionChanged += OnItemsChanged;
        AssociatedObject.RowLoaded += CheckLoadedRowIfShouldExpand;
    }

    private void CheckLoadedRowIfShouldExpand()
    {
        var iterationCopy = m_shouldBeExpanded.ToArray();
        foreach(var item in iterationCopy)
        {
            GridViewRow row = AssociatedObject.GetRowForItem( item );
            if ( row != null )
            {
                row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                m_shouldBeExpanded.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<object> m_shouldBeExpanded = new List<object>();

    private void OnItemsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (eventArgs.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (var item in eventArgs.NewItems)
            {
              GridViewRow row = AssociatedObject.GetRowForItem( item );
              if ( row == null )
              {
                // row is not loaded yet
                m_shouldBeExpanded.Add(item);
              }
              else
              {
                row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                // see http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/
                //                  controls/radgridview/row-details/programming
                // "To manually change the visibility of a row - set its
                // DetailsVisibility property to either Visibility.Collapsed
                // or Visibility.Visible"
              }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        INotifyCollectionChanged items = AssociatedObject.Items;
        items.CollectionChanged -= OnItemsChanged;
        AssociatedObject.RowLoaded -= CheckLoadedRowIfShouldExpand;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
}
```

Comment: The approach seems good overall, but it's not clear how I'm actually getting the row from the newly added item.

Comment: @ferson2020: Well, I thought you can figure that out without me. And it seems like you found the answer meanwhile. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yeah everything besides that is good. But if anyone knows how to solve that last piece, please let me know :)

Comment: @ferson2020: An edit was made to my answer by someone else. And it seems to add that last missing piece. Have you noticed?

Comment: That was me. The GetRowForItem() method seemed to be what I wanted, but it always returns null.

Comment: @ferson2020: Easy, the row for an item that returns null for GetRowForItem() is not loaded yet. Can either be caused by a virtualizing grid: Rows that are outside of the viewport are not loaded (no visual element exists) or you try to get the row too early (the item was added but the visual element representing it is not yet created). I think I can fix this.